# display partial data as and when got

Tags: php, jquery

I use jquery and php for my website. I am facing a problem. After page load, i send all the data after formatting to client and display it using jquery. mine is a products website. So i display 10 products per page. so displaying 10 products per page. Is there a way to send partial data to client and display it as and when its got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure i understand it 100%, but i think what you want is something like a pagebrowser?
If so, just write a regular Pagebrowser and use jquery to get the Data, for example with jquery load. http://api.jquery.com/load/
This is very simple to use.

Comment: i have used this. and all working fine. but page loading is slow.. so i was thinking if i can send 1st 5 products to display and then next 5 to display while 1st 5 are displaying.. so was thinking how to do this...

Comment: You can of course also send all Products on pageload, and make groups of 5 in a div each and hide all but one, and dont use load() but functions like fadeIn(), fadeOut(), hide() and show(). This will be exactly like the other solution but the data is on the client the whole time so the pageload might be a little longer, but "switching pages" will be way faster